# MySQL 5.7 equivalent to PHP's json_decode()?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm converting some php scripts into mysql stored procedures and have come across the usage of php's json_decode() on a result set's data. It occurs on a field which is stored as a mediumtext,utf8,utf8_unicode_ci

How can I perform the 'json_decode()' process using pure MySQL?

Sample data from the field:

> {"93489":{"X1":{"net":164,"vat":33.6},"X2":{"net":0,"vat":0}}}

Comment: Have you looked at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html?  json_decode coverts a string to an associative array or object, you won't really have the same types available in MySQL.

Comment: There is no MySQL 5.7 equivalent to PHP's json_decode.. You need to make it yourself in MySQL with the existing JSON functions.. MySQL 8.0 has `JSON_TABLE` ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html ) which kinda looks like PHP's json_decode because this parses out the JSON data into a table structure.

Comment: what exactly would you expect the process to achieve if you did? JSON can represent any arbitrary hierarchical data structure, for which there is not really any equivalent data type in MySQL. I would think your stored procedure should simply return the raw data. The PHP script can continue to decode it into an object for whatever purpose is needed.

Comment: Shame you're not running MySQL 8.0 as I reckon you want something like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html which converts your JSON into something iterable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function:

```
mysql> SELECT c, JSON_EXTRACT(c, "$.id"), g
     > FROM jemp
     > WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(c, "$.id") > 1
     > ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(c, "$.name");
+-------------------------------+-----------+------+
| c                             | c->"$.id" | g    |
+-------------------------------+-----------+------+
| {"id": "3", "name": "Barney"} | "3"       |    3 |
| {"id": "4", "name": "Betty"}  | "4"       |    4 |
| {"id": "2", "name": "Wilma"}  | "2"       |    2 |
+-------------------------------+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: fine if you just want one field, and/or have a super-simple data structure for your example. Not so good if you want to decode some arbitrary JSON and output all the parts.